# I want to get the anchor tag value and nested anchor tag value from single URL using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, request, concurrent.futures

I try to below code for get the anchor tag `href` and nested anchor tag value for the following URL `https://www.tradeindia.com/` but not generate the exact output. below code only get the single page URL output, can any one please suggest?

```
import concurrent

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.content


def extract_links(html_content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
    return links


def process_page(url):
    html_content = get_page(url)
    links = extract_links(html_content)
    return links


def main():
    start_url = 'https://www.tradeindia.com/'

    # Fetch the initial page
    start_page_content = get_page(start_url)

    # Extract links from the initial page
    start_page_links = extract_links(start_page_content)

    all_links = set(start_page_links)

    # Use ThreadPoolExecutor to parallelize the process
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        # Submit tasks for processing each link concurrently
        future_to_url = {executor.submit(process_page, url): url for url in start_page_links}

        # Iterate through completed tasks and update the set of all links
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
            url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                links_on_page = future.result()
                all_links.update(links_on_page)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing {url}: {e}")

    # Print all the extracted links
    print("All Links:")
    print(len(all_links))
    for link in all_links:
        print(link)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why multithreading? For a single page?

Comment: if you mean to get data from pages which you found on start page then you would have to run it in loop and `submit()` next processes with urls from `links_on_page`. And it may need to remember to visited pages because it may loop forever. So code can be much more complex

Comment: Frankly, it could be more simple with [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) instead of `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. It already uses `threads`, and it check if page was visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get urls from `start page` and you add them to `all_links` but this will not run `executor.submit()` with new urls.

It may need more complex code for this. It may need while loop which creates new `submit` using `links_on_page` and keeps on list, and another loop which checks if there are new results and get them to add to list which it will use to create new `submit`. etc.

And frankly, I would rather use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) for this because it already uses `threading` and code will be much simpler.

Normally `scrapy` needs to generate `project` with many files and folders but this code you can run without creating project. You can put all in one file and run as any other script - `python script.py`

This script also automatically write result in file `.csv`

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    allowed_domains = ['www.tradeindia.com']

    start_urls = ['https://www.tradeindia.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('\n>>> url:', response.url, '\n')

        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        
        # create items which it will save in file `CSV`
        for url in links:
            yield {'url': url}
            
        # create requests with URL so it will process next pages
        for url in links:
            yield response.follow(url)

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 10,  # default: 16
    #'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY': True,  # default: True
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,  # delays between requests to simulate real human - from `0.5*delay` to `1.5*delay`
    #'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',       # less information on screen
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}}, # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
})

c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

---

`scrapy` has also class [LinkExtractor](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) for this. And even special [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) for this.